# Chinese Reminder Theorem on Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is commutative ring with $1$, then $A,\ B$ are comaximal ideals if $$ A+B=R$$

Here I want to prove that $$ AB  = A\cap B$$

$  AB\subset A\cap B$ is trivial by definition of ideal. So we need to prove $ A\cap B \subset AB$ : Note that by comaximality we have $x+y=1,\ x\in A,\ y\in B$. Hence for $c\in A\cap B$, we have $$ c=cx+cy $$

We must show that $c\in AB$ to finish the proof. Note that $cy=c-cx\in A$ so that $$ cy=rx$$ for some $r\in R$. Hence $$ c=(c+r)x=(r_2+c)y $$ where $r_2y=cx$

But how can we complete the proof ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show $\color{Blue}{cx}$ and $\color{Green}{cy}$ are both in $AB$. Use the fact that $\color{Blue}x,\color{Green}{c}\in A$ and $\color{Blue}c,\color{Green}y\in B$ as appropriate...